# JSDoc: specifying the type of an Object passed as a parameter?

Tags: knex.js, jsdoc3

I have a method in a module. It takes an object that is an instance of a very specific class. For example:

```
    /** Validate a unit against the database's list of valid units
     * @param {Object} db - ???
     * @param {string} unit - unit to validate
     * @returns {Promise} Promise to query unit validation
     */
    validateUnit: (db, unit) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

I want to make it very clear that the db parameter is a Knex object as returned from `require('knex')({...})`.

Comment: is `@param {Knex}` not work?

Comment: It isn't, no. If use `@param {Knex}` it shows: https://i.imgur.com/PE7oq3e.png
As I temporary workaround I'll just write "Knex object" in the description... but I'd really like to do it the "right way!"

Answer (score 0):

I think on balance I'd probably use `typedef`:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Function} Knex
 */
```

Note that Knex [exports a function](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/lib/util/make-knex.js#L10-L18), not a Plain Ol' JavaScript Object. It does add properties to that function, and as we know in JS functions are also objects! However, if we do it this way, I think your IDE may display:

```
validateUnit(db: Function, unit: string)
```

which I gather is not really what you're after. If we do this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Knex
 * @property {Function} select - Select columns to retrieve
 * @see {@link https://knexjs.org|Documentation}
 */
```

we get:

[image: VSCode sample]

You could go into as much detail as you like with the properties, or keep things simple. Someone may have already exhaustively JSDoc'd Knex for you, I haven't searched! Then you've got a type you can use for your params:

```
/** Validate a unit against the database's list of valid units
 * @param {Knex} db - database instance
 * @param {string} unit - unit to validate
 * @returns {Promise} Promise to query unit validation
 */
```